# Integrating socialize SDK in android

Tags: android, socialize-sdk

[Manifest file & Activity File Image[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWmzv.png)I have imported `Android SDK` into my Project. In the `Manifest` File I tried to to add the `activity` file from the `SDK`. But it showing as `Unresolved Class`. Also I tried to Import `import com.socialize.ActionBarUtils;` its throwing a error `cannot resolve the symbol`. How to solve?.

Below is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashriskitchen">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_lg"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_lg"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".Activity.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.RecipesActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.AboutAuthActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Activity.FavouriteActivity">
        </activity>

        <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <!-- Activities Required by Socialize -->
        <activity android:name="com.socialize.ui.comment.CommentArctivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.socialize.ui.action.ActionDetailActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.socialize.ui.profile.ProfileActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.socialize.auth.facebook.FacebookActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.socialize.ui.SocializeLaunchActivity" android:noHistory="true"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Below is My build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashriskitchen"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1000
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashrikitchen.Fragments', 'src/main/java/Fragements']
        }
    }
}

android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev176-1.22.0'

}
```

This is my SDK.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.socialize:facebook:3.1.3-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.socialize:ioc:3.1.3-SNAPSHOT'
    //compile 'com.socialize:loopy:3.1.7-SNAPSHOT'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testApplicationId "com.socialize.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.socialize.SocializeTestRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTest.setRoot('../test')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

def isReleaseBuild() {
    return VERSION_NAME.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

def getReleaseRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL') ? RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL
            : "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
}

def getSnapshotRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL') ? SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL
            : "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}

def getRepositoryUsername() {
    return hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
}

def getRepositoryPassword() {
    return hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""
}

if (hasProperty('GROUP')) {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        uploadArchives {
            repositories {
                mavenDeployer {
                    beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                    pom.groupId = GROUP
                    pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
                    pom.version = VERSION_NAME

                    repository(url: getReleaseRepositoryUrl()) {
                        authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                    }
                    snapshotRepository(url: getSnapshotRepositoryUrl()) {
                        authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                    }

                    pom.project {
                        name POM_NAME
                        packaging POM_PACKAGING
                        description POM_DESCRIPTION
                        url POM_URL

                        scm {
                            url POM_SCM_URL
                            connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                            developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                        }

                        licenses {
                            license {
                                name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                                url POM_LICENCE_URL
                                distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                            }
                        }

                        developers {
                            developer {
                                id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                                name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        signing {
            required { isReleaseBuild() && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
            sign configurations.archives
        }

        task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
            source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
            classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
            excludes = ['**/i18n.properties', '**/default.socialize.properties', '**/socialize_core_beans.xml', '**/socialize_notification_beans.xml', '**/socialize_ui_beans.xml', '**/socialize.errors.properties']
        }

        task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
            classifier = 'javadoc'
            from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
        }

        task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
            classifier = 'sources'
            from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
        }

        artifacts {
            archives androidSourcesJar
            archives androidJavadocsJar
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using android studio?

Comment: Yes.Am using Android studio

Comment: Please show the build.gradle file and the entire error message.

Comment: I followed the below link.. "http://socialize.github.io/socialize-sdk-android/getting_started.html"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly what you have in your own code.

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: Please post text, not a screen shot

Comment: Is this (https://github.com/socialize/socialize-sdk-android) the SDK you are trying to add?

Comment: Yes. Am using the above sdk